# htmlTable producing row numbers

Tags: r, html-table

I'm putting a table into an RMarkdown presentation and it is producing erroneous row numbers in the output I've got this:

```
library(htmlTable)

d <- data.frame(
    x=c('1','2','3'),
    y=c('A','B','C')
)

htmlTable(d)
```

[image: Here's a picture of the output]

How do I remove these?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Set `rnames` equals to `FALSE`.

````
---
title: "htmlTable"
output: html_document
---


```{r setup, include=FALSE}
knitr::opts_chunk$set(echo = TRUE)
```


```{r}
library(htmlTable)

d <- data.frame(
    x=c('1','2','3'),
    y=c('A','B','C')
)

htmlTable(d, rnames = FALSE)
```
````

Comment: Just the thing - thanks!

Comment: From the documentation: `rnames` Default row names are generated from `rownames(x)`. If you provide `FALSE` then
it will skip the row names. Note: For data.frames if you do `rownames(my_dataframe)
<- NULL` it still has row names. Thus you need to use FALSE if you want to su-
press row names for data.frames.

Comment: @TarJae, oh ok. Sorry didn't understand at first.

Answer (score 0):

```
library("xtable")

d <- data.frame(
    x=c('1','2','3'),
    y=c('A','B','C')
)

print(xtable(d), type="html", include.rownames = FALSE)
```

Comment: I've had bigger problems getting xtable to work for my purposes. The documentation for htmlTable (https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/htmlTable/vignettes/general.html) shows basically everything I need, but it's not clear why what I'm doing is producing those row numbers.

Comment: Have you tried using the rnames function inside the htmltable?